# Linux permission to execute but deny editing

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, system-administration

I've a script on my server, in which the user must be able to execute but not edit it. Anyone know if it's possible to restrict that based on file permissions?

Comment: Shouldn't r+x permissions work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
chmod a=x your_script.sh
```

That only allows executions for everyone to your script. Change the 'a' for the target you want to modify the permission ('a'=all, 'g'=group, 'o'=others, 'u'=owner/user)

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible. It is exactly what file permissions do - give you control over what owner,group,all can do to a file.

One appropriate mode would be - chmod 555 - as you need also the "r" permission in order to execute, and script in some public location like /usr/local/bin